# Is it possible to use both query_string and segment based url routing in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I have created an application and created two folder in Controller.

```
1)frontend (User Panel)
2)backend (Admin Panel)
```

Structure of Controller :

```
--application
  --controller
    --frontend
       --product.php
       --customer.php
    --backend
      --admin.php
      --order.php
```

I am using config setting :

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';

$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

I am using this Url format for backend(Admin Panel),

```
http://localhost/DemoApp/index.php?c=admin_controller&m=customer_order&d=backend
```

But for frontend(User Panel) I want to use segment based URL :

```
http://localhost/DemoApp/user_controller/customer
```

Is it possible to use ? and any other choice to do both type of URL Pattern.

Comment: How can i do it ? give me some tips and reference links.

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html for get the values of different url types

Comment: what is the specific problem? You can easily use query strings in controller routes and turn off `enable_query_strings`

Comment: if i turn off `enable_query_strings` i got this error `The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.` for this url `http://localhost/DemoApp/index.php?c=admin_controller&m=customer_order&d=backend`

Comment: @SRK Please don't link to the EllisLab website for CodeIgniter documentation - it's outdated. The *official* documentation is at codeigniter.com.

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible, but the framework is not designed to allow that. Or in other words - it's not as simple as figuring out the right configuration values.

Rather, you need to figure out a way to use *different* configurations based on the URI and that logic must be executed before the framework itself is initialized (i.e. changing the configuration at runtime won't work).

You can do that from inside the index.php file.